# Creating trigger in PL/SQL oracle 9

Tags: plsql

I'M trying to create a trigger  based on the question on the image on the link below . but i'm struggling to handle duplicates on update and to handle maximum character length on insert and update. here is my solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_author
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT  ON bk_author
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_authorid bk_author.authorid%type;
BEGIN
IF UPDATING THEN
IF LENGTH(:NEW.fname) > 10 THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Author name cannot exceed 10 characters');
END IF;
ELSIF INSERTING THEN
SELECT authorid
INTO v_authorid
FROM bk_author
WHERE authorid = :NEW.authorid;
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'Author id already existing cannot be added');
IF LENGTH(:NEW.fname) > 10 THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Author name cannot exceed 10 characters');
END IF;

END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Author '||:NEW.authorid||' added');
END;
/
```

Comment: 1. why you check field length with trigger but not with constraints or constrainted field type? Is it required?
2. when you select existed you don't check that it exists or not you alwais raise errors
3. why you not check LENGTH(:NEW.fname) before checking of UPDATING INSERTING -to avoid code duplicity?

Comment: 1 I'm using trigger, to answer a particular school work question that i was asked, to raise application error if field maximum length exceeded.   2. I'm not using existing values and names can be duplicate. only ID need to be checked if exists.                                                3. I will try to check the length before updating or inserting to see if it cannot work , as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check condition to raise error about duplicate, it's executing no matter is there ID in database or not.

you should add IF before it

something like

```
ELSIF INSERTING THEN
SELECT authorid
INTO v_authorid
FROM bk_author
WHERE authorid = :NEW.authorid;
IF v_authorid is not null then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,'Author id already existing cannot be 
  added');
 end if;
```

Comment: He's using negative confirmation to check for duplicates, where if the select doesn't find anything, he jumps to the exception block for NO_DATA_FOUND.

Comment: Hi it seems ok now with authorid ,  my challenge now is on name maximum length validation, my trigger still doesn't throw exception when i enter longer firstname.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it should work for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_author
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT  ON bk_author
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
v_authorid number;
BEGIN
IF UPDATING THEN
IF LENGTH(:NEW.fname) > 10 THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Author name cannot exceed 10 characters');
END IF;
ELSIF INSERTING THEN
SELECT count(authorid) INTO v_authorid
FROM bk_author
WHERE authorid = :NEW.authorid;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Author id already existing cannot be added');
RAISE;
IF LENGTH(:NEW.fname) > 10 THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Author name cannot exceed 10 characters');
RAISE;
END IF;

END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Author '||:NEW.authorid||' added');
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi thanks,i tried this solution,still the trigger doesn't fire when i try to enter longer firstname.